# Make g++ output a warning when comparing variable to itself

Tags: g++

I spent time debugging some code and the problem's root cause was a typo, that made the code compare a variable to itself and not another variable.

It seems that enabling `-Wall` and `-Wextra` does not issue any warnings regarding comparison of variables with itself.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(){
  int ia = 123;
  if(ia != ia){
    std::cout << " != " << std::endl;
  }
}
```

The above code compiles without warnings even if `-Wall` and `-Wextra` are used.
Is there a way to make g++ generate a warning message when a variable is compared to itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a newer GCC version.  GCC 8 prints:

```
t.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
t.cc:5:9: warning: self-comparison always evaluates to false [-Wtautological-compare]
   if(ia != ia){
      ~~~^~~~~
```

This was implemented for [GCC PR 66555](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66555).  GCC 6 is the first GCC version with this warning.